# Width at 100% but content still not filling up the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to build a responsive website with HTML, CSS and Bootstrap 4, but seem to be facing problems with getting my carousel width to fill up 100% of the screen of Pixel 2 XL (landscape - w: 823px) and iPad (portrait - w: 768px). (See images attached)

For the other screen modes, they fill up 100% perfectly. Not so sure what's wrong. I have tried setting the body and the parent to width: 100% but still does not work for the above 2 screens.

[pixel 2 XL landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYUfe.jpg)

[iPad portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k26yH.jpg)

Here are my code:

Carousel item:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img src="cats.jpg" alt="cats" width="1280" height="400">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h2>Your Cat is Happy</h2>
       <p>Feed it more treats!</p>
       <button type="button" class="btn">BUY TREATS</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS (normal):

```
.carousel-inner img {
    filter: brightness(70%);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.carousel-caption {
    width:100%;
    max-height: 50%;
    left:0;
    margin-bottom:9%;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 60px;
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    -webkit-animation-name: caption_animation; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-name: caption_animation;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

.carousel-item img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

CSS (max-width of screen):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1025px){
    .carousel-item img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 60%;
    }

    .carousel-caption {
        margin-bottom: 130px;
        font-size: 12px;
        -webkit-animation-name: caption_animation 1s 1;
        animation-name: caption_animation 1s 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jones, I may help you. But please also share css of .carousel-caption and .carousel-item

Comment: Hey @Rakesh , updated as above. Tried the suggested answers below, doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.carousel-inner img {
    display: block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    filter: brightness(70%);
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nsrpRz/111.jpg" alt="cats" width="1280" height="400">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
       <h2>Your Cat is Happy</h2>
       <p>Feed it more treats!</p>
       <button type="button" class="btn">BUY TREATS</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no need to set `height: 100%` to image for responsive purpose, please have a look at the below updated working snippet, hope it helps :)

```css
.carousel-item img {
  filter: brightness(70%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Carousel item: -->
<div class="carousel-item">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/1280/400" alt="cats">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h2>Your Cat is Happy</h2>
    <p>Feed it more treats!</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn">BUY TREATS</button>
  </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `width:100%` to img as shown below:

```
   .carousel-item img{
      width:100%;
    }
```